# Style a list view data template in resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following style in a resource dictionary:

```
 <!--  A style for list views that only display images  -->
    <Style x:Key="ImageListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FandFCream}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <!--  Use a wrap panel so that the items appear side by side rather than stacked vertically  -->
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <!--  Changes the colour of a selected item and keeps that colour when the focus is lost  -->
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource Green}" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource Green}" />
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <!--  Change the item template  -->
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <!--  A border around each item  -->
                    <Border Name="ItemBorder" Style="{StaticResource FandFItemBorderStyle}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

What I want is to be able to display an image in the border that is in the data template. How can I do this so that I can reuse this style in several control but be able to bind the image source to a view model?

For example I was thinking that if the style was something like:

```
<DataTemplate>
      <!--  A border around each item  -->
      <Border Name="ItemBorder" Style="{StaticResource FandFItemBorderStyle}">
           <ContentPresenter />
      </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then I could do maybe assign an image object to the list view in that content control, but I am not sure how to actually do this.

- WPF
- C#
- Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Will the style be used for custom controls or existing ones?

Comment: I have many controls and windows that use a list view, and currently each is defining the same template/style in its own view. so I wanted to create a single style which defined all the style data to tidy things up

Comment: Okay, do you want that image to be static per control or do you need it to relate to the current item in the list?

Comment: The list view will bind to an observable collection in the viewmodel. One property of each item in the observable collection is a bitmap source image. so I would like the list view to display 20 images. once loaded they will only change according to the content of the observable collection

Comment: Anything stopping you from binding to that image property in the datatemplate?

Comment: Could you explain more about what you mean please/

Comment: Something like putting an ImageView inside the datatemplate and bind it's Source property to the property in your viewmodels.